# Extract all links from a database table using SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I need to extarct all links from a database so I can create a URL rewrite. Using a SQL statement, how can I extract just links from a table? Sometimes there is more than one link within a cell which further complicates it. Any idea on how to achieve this?

**EDIT**
An example of this would be: SELECT myval FROM htmlcontrols.
"myval" has an HTML string such as "`<div>Hi this is a test. <a href="somewhere.htm">Click here</a> or <a href="http://somewhereelse.com/testarea">here</a></div>`". I want an extract like this:

```
LINKS
-----
somewhere.htm
http://somewhereelse.com/testarea
```

Comment: You'll need to show an example of the query so far, and what your data might look like. There's lots of (bad) ways to store multi-valued attributes.

Comment: From the Question, I'd say that there are text fields with html in them.  And the OP needs to strip out each and every link from those html strings.

Comment: @Dems Right, but delimiters are important for one thing. Is it just text with links in the mix, as you said? Or a field that may have 1+ links separated by `| ; \t \r\n`...?

Comment: Thanks I modified my question with the extra details. There is no multi-valued attributes.. just a plain HTML string column.

Comment: This would be easier with CLR and Regex (or CLR and HTML parser dependant on degree of accuracy required)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You are probably better off either handling this on the client side, iterating through the fields and parsing the HTML to then re-insert them on whatever table/columns you need to; or at least, [creating a UDF](http://www.ideaexcursion.com/2009/08/18/sql-server-regular-expression-clr-udf/) that can do the parsing efficiently.

Note that the link I posted above is an implementation of a UDF RegEx function but **I am not** suggesting necessarily that you should use a RegEx to parse HTML as this is [almost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4231382/regular-expression-pattern-not-matching-anywhere-in-string/4234491#4234491) always [a bad idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454).

If you go with the CLR function, take a look at [HTMLAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/)

Comment: Dead links - making the answer pretty much useless.